# How to select days in whole year by selecting drop down options in full calendar and added it to datatable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatables, fullcalendar

I have full calendar. Designs as follows:

```
<div class="box-body no-padding">
  <div id="calendar_full">
  </div>
</div>
```

I am having a drop down box:
Design as follows:

```
<div class="col-md-8  col-lg-8">
   <input id="chkBoxDay1" name="chkBoxDay1 " type="checkbox" />
   <label>Day 1</label>
   <select id="dropdownDay1" disabled="disabled">
    <option value="Sunday">Sunday</option>
    <option value="Monday">Monday</option>
    <option value="Tuesday">Tuesday</option>
    <option value="Wednesday">Wednesday</option>
    <option value="Thursday">Thursday</option>
    <option value="Friday">Friday</option>
    <option value="Saturday">Saturday</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

My datatable design:

```
<table id="dttable" class="table table-striped table-hover table-bordered table-hd">
<thead>
<tr class="gridheader">
  <td valign="middle" align="center" style="width: 2%;"></td>
  <td style="width: 50%;" class="search_field" search_field_value="CalendarDate">Calendar Date</td>
  <td style="width: 50%;" class="search_field" search_field_value="Description">Description</td>
 </tr>
 </thead>
   <tbody>
    <tr>
     <td></td>
     <td></td>
     <td></td>
    </tr>
   </tbody>
  </table>
```

and also I have a button as follows:

```
<div class="btn-group">
<a id="btnLoadCalendar" name="btnLoadCalendar" onclick="LoadCalendar()" class="btn btn-block btn-success btn-flat"><span class="hide-on-mobile">Load Calendar </span><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></a>
</div>
```

What I am trying to do is, when I click the Load Calendar button (after I enable my checkbox and select any day from my drop down), my full calendar year's-all days(selected type day) must be highlighted or background color need to change and those whole list needs to add under my datatable.

Let's say, if I choose Monday, my calender's whole year's Mondays must be selected and  the text 'selected day' will be displayed in cell and also those whole set of Mondays must be added to my datatable.

Here is the script I tried

```
<script>
function LoadCalendar() {
   var t = $('#dttable).DataTable();
   var counter = 1;
   var Day1 = document.getElementById('chkBoxDay1');
   var WDay1 = $("#dropdownDay1").children("option:selected").val();   
  if ((Day1.checked) == false) {
    alert("Please Select Weekend Day option");
  }
  else if {
   var WorDay1 = WDay1.substring(0, 3);
   while (WorDay1 ) {
    $('.fc-'+WorDay1 ).each(function(date,jsEvent,view) {
     $(this).css('background-color', "#008080");
      t.row.add([
      counter,
      date('dddd,MMMM DD,YYYY'),
      Day1.val()
  ]).draw(false);     
counter++;
});
}
// $('.fc-day.fc-'+WorDay1).css('backgroundColor', '#008080');
}
}   
</script>
```

How to do this?  I tried few answers, but none replicate mine.

Comment: why do you want to do this, exactly? What is the purpose of the requirement? Are you trying to create recurring events, or something?

Comment: @ADyson Select all Mondays(for whole year-if its 2018 means -from jan 2018 to dec 2018 all mondays) from calendar by choosing Monday from dropdown, ighlight its cell's color and when I press load button, those selected list of Mondays must be added to my datatable, is what I want

Comment: @halfer sorry As my deadline is today, I mention as Urgent

Comment: Sure, but your readers are volunteers, and some of them will ignore your question if they see that you think your question should jump to the head of the queue. It really is counterproductive to add such material - and if you read that link in its entirety, you'll see that people feel this quite strongly.

Comment: @ADyson Oh sorry once again, I know you guys are doing great job, but I dont know about this urgent keyword is so sensitive here. Why I need is, I need to set my selected year's selected day(lets assume Monday) as Half Day or Off Day to the staff, that to be displayed in my calendar first(by background color change) and also add to my datatable as I set this to selected staff

Comment: Hmm, I think for this you might be better to to add a [background event](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/background-events) which is [recurring](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/recurring-events) . It's easier to do that than to try and change the CSS of fullCalendar (especially to repeat on days which aren't yet visible).

Comment: I understand. Thank u for ur reply I am trying those bg event now